# How to print a chain of arrows with fprintf

Tags: matlab, printf

I am looking for a way to set up the `fprintf` function so that it returns the string `1->2->...->n` for any input n. However, I cannot find a way to do so without having an extra arrow attached at the beginning (`->1->2->...->n`) or the end of the string (`1->2->...->n->`). Is there a way around this?

Comment: I did, but it keeps printing it on a different line. How can I get two ```fprintf``` functions to print on the same line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `strjoin` for this...

```
n = 4;
str = strjoin( arrayfun(@num2str, 1:n, 'uni', 0), '->' );

% str = '1->2->3->4'
```

Or if you're set on using `fprintf` (or `sprintf`), you could manually add the first element (for ease, assume `n >= 1`)

```
str = ['1', sprintf('->%.0f', 2:n )];
```

If you just want to print these to the Command Window, simply use `disp` on either option instead of (or after) assigning to `str`. If you're writing to a file with `fprintf` then simply use `fprintf( fid, [str '\n'] )` to print the line to file.

Comment: Interesting solution with `strjoin`, haven’t seen that one used a lot.

Comment: it's pretty useful because it handles exactly these edge cases! Good for building delimited strings from a cell array (e.g. comma-separated lists)

Comment: @Marco: If this solution is useful to you, please mark it as accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

For this type of task, the solution is to print either the first or the last element separately:

```
n = 8;
fprintf('%d', 1);
fprintf('->%d', 2:n);
fprintf('\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach to build the desired string:

```
n = 10;
str = regexprep(num2str(1:n), '\s+', '->');
```

This gives

```
str =
    '1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->9->10'
```